# Divergence of Cosine integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How to prove that the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x}dx$$
diverges (I'm looking for an elegant argument, preferably without deriving  Euler-Mascheroni constant and all that).

**A (not so elegant) attempt** Pick a positive number $a< \frac{\pi}{2}$. Since $\cos x$ is a decreasing function for $x \in [0,a]$ then $\cos a \leq \cos x$ and in particular $$\cos a \int_0^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx \leq \int_0^{a}\frac{\cos x}{x}dx$$
Since the first integral diverges to $+\infty$, so does the second. And it suffice now to show that the integral for $[a, \infty)$ is either finite or diverges to positive infinity.

For $x \in [a, \frac{3}{2}\pi]$, we have $\frac{\cos x}{x} < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{a}$ and the integral is bounded above by $\frac{3/2\pi - a}{a}$ (A similar argument for below). Finally, for all integers $k>0$, note that $\cos x \geq 0$ for $x \in [\frac{4k-1}{2}\pi, \frac{4k+1}{2}\pi]$ and $\cos x = -\cos (x-\pi)$. Then

$$\begin{align}{\large\int}_{\frac{4k-1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{4k+1}{2}\pi}\frac{\cos x}{x}dx + {\large\int}_{\frac{4k+1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{4k+3}{2}\pi}\frac{\cos x}{x}dx &= {\large\int}_{\frac{4k-1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{4k+1}{2}\pi}\frac{\cos x}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{x+\pi}dx
\\&={\large\int}_{\frac{4k-1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{4k+1}{2}\pi}\frac{\pi \cos x}{x(x+\pi)}dx
\end{align}$$
the integral is non-negative since the integrand is non-negative in the interval.

Comment: You only need the first part of your proof, which showed that $\int_0^a \frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,dx$ diverges.  The second part is not required, but one can appeal to Abel's test (or simply integrate by parts) to show that $\int_a^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,dx$ converges for all $a>0$.